# Liquid filter date in Logic App is not working as expected

Tags: azure, liquid, azure-logic-apps

I have a very simple map written in Liquid and executed in a Logic App.
The map contains only this :

```
{
    "myDate": "{{ "now" }}"
}
```

The ouput of the map is

```
 {
    "myDate": "Now"
 }
```

According to the Liquid documentation it is the right way to generate the current datetime. I tried to put the N in uppercase but it does not work.

Maybe there is a list of supported Liquid features somewhere?
I also tried to apply filters like the `date` filter in order to change the format of a datetime, but the map is not working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to format the output as this example

```
{
   "Date" : "{{ "now" | Date: "MM/dd/yyyy" }}"
}
```

Comment: 'now' not working even with the format. It still prints 'now' not the date